# Main clauses from minimal pairs

Tags: word-play

In Latin it is possible to create sentences from two identical words (homonym or homogram), or two minimal pairs.

> **Puro puro**, I ritually purify with a bonfire.
>   **Ēquus ĕquus**, The horse is
>   steady (aequus, even, steady, becomes medieval ēquus)

The only classical quote known to me that approaches this is Cicero's

> O fortunatam natam me consule Romam.

"O fortunate state for my natal date and Consulate"...and he was assassinated soon after. Jingle and rhyme doesn't become acceptable until 400.

So, does anyone know of a collection of these two-word sentences.
If any more individual examples are known to you, I would be very happy to hear of them.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you asked for, but these two verses from Ennius might be interesting: "*At tuba terribili sonitu taratantara dixit*" and "*O Tite tute Tati tibi tanta tyranne tulisti*". Are these close to what you are looking for?

Comment: Many thanks @Joonas Ilmavirta, Good for the changing aesthetic; really good. But in the end I'm hoping for some  Carolingian courtier or Knight Templar who has collected jingles, the way the Exeter Book collects riddles.

Comment: There's *malo malo malo malo*  (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_mnemonics#Examples_and_analysis), though I don't know its origin and it's probably post-Classical.

Comment: @TKR - that citation led indirectly to 500 images on Google for the minimal pair from Tacitus *Amantes amentes* (=Lovers are insane). Very useful: loads of thanks.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, but here's [an anecdote](http://www.dmgh.de/de/fs1/object/goToPage/bsb00000687.html?pageNo=59&sortIndex=010%3A060%3A0007%3A010%3A00%3A00) about what the jurist Bulgarus said after he denied that Frederick Barbarossa was *dominus mundi* 'quantum ad proprietatem'. Another jurist, Martinus, said that he was, and was awarded a horse. Bulgarus (reportedly) declaimed: 'Amisi equum, quia dixi equum, quod non fuit equum.' If the above link rots, see F. Güterbock, ed., *Das Geschichtswerk des Otto Morena und seiner Fortsetzer über*... (SS rer. Germ.; Berlin 1930), 59.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TKR pointed out, *malo malo* works. I think you might have a difficult time finding them, because they're actually abundant. Getting several to stack is where the fun is.

As an example about how easy this is:

> amor amor | I, Love, am loved.
>
> Servas servas | You keep the slave women safe.
>
> Servo servo | I protect from the slave.
>
> Eo eo | I am going there.
>
> Rege rege | Rule by means of a king
>
> Laudes laudes | You should praise the praises.

Now, the real challenge is getting more than two.

Comment: unde unde? Where are these waves coming from?
oleo oleo, I smell of olive oil.

Comment: @cnread *oleo oleo* surely, but I think *unde unde* is disqualified by not actually being a complete sentence (even if it's perfectly acceptable in Latin, true). Hugh's fine with Medieval ae -> e, but I could never get over it!

Comment: Wonderful.  I had *regulo regulo* 'I rule by principle;and *abeo  ab eo* which fits Quintilian's criteria, but not the OP.

Comment: Laude doesn't work: it's first conjugation

Comment: @cnread _servio_ means “to serve”, but [_servo, as, āvi, ātum, āre_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dservo) means “to preserve”. _Servo servo_ means “I save for the servant.”

Comment: @cnread We probably should delete these comments. Typical SE policy is to delete comments like these when they are no longer necessary. I'll start (and delete this one, too, in a couple days).

Answer (score 4):

The only such sentence that is used “in the wild”, according to my knowledge, is ***soli soli soli.*** It consists of the two datives of *solus* and *sol* followed by the genitive of *solum.* The meaning (a bit stretched) is “to the only Sun of the Earth.” You can read it on several sundials in Italy, France and possibly other countries.

[image]

This is in Nanteuil, France (you’ll also notice the Roman numerals *I* to *XII* and *MM* for the year when it was built.) I got the photo from
http://michel.lalos.free.fr/cadrans_solaires/autres_depts/deux_sevres/cs_deux_sevres_niort.html

Unfortunately, I couldn’t find attestations earlier than the 19th century. I suspect the motto is more ancient. Several sources I have seen (including on paper) link it to Napoleon, who with his usual modesty would have thought of himself as the “only Sun”, but I couldn’t isolate a single, reliable reference.

Comment: Magnificent.  Would it be churlish to suggest that your source should have written "Au Soleil de la seule Terre"? perhaps even, 'la Terre isolée' in reference to our lonely planet.